# Is it possible to have variable text sizes in UITextView? (Making a tag cloud)

Tags: xcode, uitextview, tag-cloud

I would like to create a tag cloud of sorts, and I thought of using a UITextView. Is it possible to have variable text sizes in a UITextView? If not, any other suggestions on which UI elements to use to generate a tag cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend programmatically adding `UILabel` objects as needed. You can only have one font size per `UITextView`, plus `UITextView` is generally for editable text. Just roughly, you could use something like this:

```
 UILabel *example = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:<#(CGRect)#>];
 [example setFont:<#(UIFont *)#>];
 [example setText:<#(NSString *)#>];
 [self.view addSubview:example];
```

You can put it in a loop and fill in the blanks.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking to just go with individual UILabels, but a UITextView would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible in iOS 6 (if you can wait that long) since Apple is finally adding the possibility to use `NSAttributedString` in `UITextView`.